# PegarCidade não existe no tipo 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

Este código abaixo é do arquivo entrega.ts de uma página em Ionic 3.9

Bairro e cidade são dados pegos de uma api no localhost

É apresentado para mim dois erros que não sei como resolver:

> Property 'PegarCidade' does not exist on type 'string'.
>
> Property 'PegarBairro' does not exist on type 'string'.

**Código:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpProvider } from '../../providers/http/http';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-entrega',
  templateUrl: 'entrega.html',
})

export class EntregaPage {

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    private httpProvider : HttpProvider) {
    this.addCidade();
  }
  public listaCidades = [];
  public listaBairros = [];
  public exibirCamposText : boolean = false;
  city : string;
  neighborhood : string; 

  url = 'http://127.0.0.1/'

 public PegarBairro(){
   this.httpProvider.url = this.url + 'bairros' + '/cidades';
   return this.httpProvider.get();
  }

public PegarCidade(){
  this.httpProvider.url = this.url + 'cidades';
  return this.httpProvider.get();
}

 public addCidade(){
  this.city.PegarCidade().subscribe(
    (retorno : any) =>{
      this.listaCidades = retorno;
    }
  )
}

 public clickcidade(){
   this.listarBairos();
 }

 public listarBairos(){
   this.neighborhood.PegarBairro(this.city).subscribe(
     (resultado : any) =>{
       this.listaBairros = resultado;
      }
      )
    }
    
    public clicktext(){
      this.exibirCamposText = !this.exibirCamposText;
    }
    
    public resetar(){
      this.city = null;
      this.listaBairros = [];
      this.exibirCamposText = !this.exibirCamposText;
      this.addCidade();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

**É um erro de digitação**

Na sua classe tem isto:

```
city : string;
```

E aqui você tentou acessar o método `PegarCidade()` da variável `this.city`:

```
  this.city.PegarCidade().subscribe(
    (retorno : any) =>{
      this.listaCidades = retorno;
    }
  )
```

Mas `PegarCidade()` é um método da classe `EntregaPage` e o correto deveria ser apenas:

```
 this.PegarCidade().subscribe(
    (retorno : any) =>{
      this.listaCidades = retorno;
    }
  )
```

O `this.neighborhood.PegarBairro` também deveria ser isto `this.PegarBairro`

Comment: Obrigado, mas como ficaria isto se escrito corretamente?
Property 'PegarBairro' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: @jharckness é o mesmo erro, é só olhar, todos métodos que você esta tentando acessar ao invés de acessar via THIS você tentou acessar das variaveis que são strings, você fez isso `this.neighborhood.PegarBairro` quando deveria ter feito isso: `this.PegarBairro`.

Comment: Obrigado, tudo funcionando.